# Setting up a 'Search Text in Project' shortcut in Springsource?

Tags: eclipse, ide, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm working in STS 3.1.0, and I use the Search->Text->Project menu item a lot (and workspace, file as well). I've looked through the Command Availability options, menu options and such. I don't see a way to add this command to either the toolbar or better, a keyboard shortcut.

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: menu]

Am I missing something or is it not possible?

Comment: The instasearch plugin looks like it might be configurable, but all I really want is a keyboard shortcut. I've got a lot of plugins already. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch#.ULjVoIUYJFQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to preferences (cmd+, on mac as far I remember) then General>Keys and search for the action you need to add the keybinding.

Here is a snapshot of the keys that might interest you
[image: search]

Comment: I'm so used to messing with the perspective customization dialog, I forgot about general preferences.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using STS 3.3 or later version - you can just do (CTRL+SHIFT+L or CMD+SHIFT+L on Mac) opens the below dialog from any context and get instant search results.

[image]